# Azure Multi region DR : Custom Routing Policies in APIM[Premium) Vs Traffic Manager behind APIM

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager

We have APIM premium, which comes with internal Traffic Manager for performance base routing .
If APIM is integrated externally with the vnet in which we have our fnapp integrated, for multiregional DR  ,the MS docs are suggesting to use custom apim policies or traffic manager but couldn’t find anything on considerations for choosing one over another .

Most of the reference architecture talking about APIM internal vnet integration. There is no docs on APIM external>TM >AGW>APPSERVICE

Can I get more clarity on the following queries

1. Is there any advantage of using this TM  over custom policy routing? I think since the Traffic manager deploys multiple probes from multiple locations for each endpoint. Multiple probes increase resiliency for endpoint monitoring.
2. If we use TM ,we need publicly available endpoint to probe and since we have all our backed inside vnet, we need regional application gateway to talk those backed services .
   Is the traffic between APIM to TM AND TM to AGW use backbone network?
3. If we use priority based probing ,after the failover to secondary ,when the primary function has returned to a healthy state and cashes are refreshed ,does the Traffic Manager  failsback to primary  or it will continue to serve the request from secondary until it is healthy?
   Docs are mentioning conflicting points on this one
4. Is APIM internal vnet with agw for external access [hybrid access]   a recommended approach  as compared to external vnet integration for the above mentioned scenario? In this case we may also need to add additional TM  before AGW for multiregion request  TM>AGW>APIM. Paying for premium apim and for an additional TM [while Premium APIM have an inbuilt TM] looks like an overkill .

Answer (score 0):

[Reshma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9724190/reshma): Stack overflow is for more of programmatical problems but I found an article that might help you out.

Majority of your concerns are addressed at https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/load-balancing-public-and-private-traffic-to-azure-api-management. Hope this helps you bring out the differentiation between two.

Comment: As I mentioned elsewhere: Please don't post link-only answers. Also: the question is off-topic as written - it's *very* broad (many questions in one), and opinion-soliciting. Not something you should be answering here.